# Gsuite email with phpmailer not sending email to live email address

Tags: php, phpmailer, digital-ocean

I have setup gsuite email and want to use it for emails that my website sends when someone registers etc. I have setup phpmailer to do that.

```
$email = new PHPMailer(); 
$email->Host = "stmp.gmail.com"; 
$email->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$email->SMTPAuth = true; 
$email->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 
$email->Port = 465; 
$email->Username = "myemail@mydomain.com"; 
$email->Password = "password"; 
$email->AddReplyTo('myemail@mydomain.com', "My Email"); 
$email->SetFrom('myemail@mydomain.com', "My Email"); 
$email->AddAddress("email@gmail.com"); 
$email->AddAddress("email@live.com"); 
$email->Subject = "test email"; 
$email->MsgHTML("<a>This is test</a>"); 
$email->Send();
```

I have tried to change subject/content of the email, also tried tls/587 but it sends email to gmail but not to live which I think I don't want to miss out.

Comment: Where does Digital Ocean feature in this?

Comment: Have you allowed less secure app for your email. You need to allow it in order to use it as smtp. Here is the link https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: Yes it works well to send email to gmail address.

Comment: @Redd, I'm hosting my website on digital-ocean droplet.

Comment: Just because you're using Digital Ocean doesn't automatically make this a [tag:digital-ocean] question. Please only tag [tag:digital-ocean] if the question specifically has something to do with Digital Ocean.

Comment: I beg to differ as on another host same code works well. Maybe my ip is problematic that is assigned by digital-ocean. Or maybe digital-ocean have some limit/rules on outgoing emails. I have tagged it so if some have used it might help me. Thanks

Comment: In that case, you should [edit] your question to make that distinction.

Comment: Putting aside the hope of getting answer here, can you answer the question if I make that distinction?

Comment: Although you are not bound to.

Comment: When you say "sends to gmail but not to live", what do you mean exactly? Show your SMTP transcript. If it's submitting to gmail, then this is nothing to do with Digital Ocean as they can't see inside your TLS connection. If it's successfully submitting via gmail, then you don't have a sending problem; you have a receiving problem, so check your spam folder on live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my ip was listed in spamhaus, which they cleared after I contacted them. Now I receive emails on live.com as well.

[image]